# Getting Value of two TextViews in Custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a CustomAdapter with two textviews.  I need to grab the value/string of each.

I can grab the first one by doing this:

```
List<String> dataList;
List<String> catList; 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long id) {

firstTextView = dataList.get(arg2); // This grabs TextView #1
secondTextView = catList. ???

// later on


adapter = new SearchAdapter(SearchableActivity.this, dataList, catList);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

How do I get the second value?  I can't create an arg3 obviously

Any ideas?

Edit:  Or is this not doable for ArrayAdapter and I need to create something more custom with, say, BaseAdapter?

Comment: I have a List<String> "array".  That was an bad choice.  The actual name is dataList.  I will edit text not to confuse.

Comment: maintain seperate arrays for two textviews in list view and get those values by listposition

Comment: See edited question; I do have two arrays.  Thanks for your help!  Can you show code on how to get values?

Comment: so why not use `secondTextView = catList.get(arg2);`. btw how you are setting the adapter to your `listView`?

Comment: it crashes when I do that.  I added updated code to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the second parameter of the `onItemClick` method:

```
TextView first = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.first_textview);
String s1 = first.getText().toString();
TextView second = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.second_textview);
String s2 = second.getText().toString();
```

Maybe it would be better to just return a special object from your adapter that incorporates the two strings like:

```
class DataStructure {
    String s1, s2
}
```

and return this from this adapter.